# Android, Mapbox, location, Java

Tags: java, android, location, mapbox

I have created an Android map using Mapbox. My map displays with the location that I have set in activity_main.xml. When I click on a button, system find the 'current location' and adding the marker in that location successfully. But the problem here is, my map is not actually moving to that current location automatically. How do I do achieve this? It is always
    displaying the location that I have set in activity_main.xml.

**Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
private MapView mapView;
private MapboxMap map; //right now your map variable is null. In getMapAsync, you need to initialize map = mapboxMap;
Button myButton;
protected LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MapboxAccountManager.start(this, "myToken");
    final boolean permissionGranted = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.locate1);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

                            Log.i("MapAsync", " is called");
                            //you need to initialize 'map' with 'mapboxMap'; 
                            map = mapboxMap;

                        }

                    });
    final GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
    // On click on the 'Locate' button should add a 'new marker on map' with current location lat long 
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (permissionGranted){
                // check if GPS is enabled
                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

                    gps.location = gps.getLocation();

                    final double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    final double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                                    .title("Hello user !")
                                    .snippet("Welcome to mapbox"));
                            //Adding the camera here as suggeted
                            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                    .target(new LatLng(gps.location.getLatitude(), gps.location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
                                    .zoom(12)                   // Sets the zoom
                                    .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                                    .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                                    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder   

                           map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                    //  \n is for new line
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                } else {
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }

            }else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 200);
            }

        }
    });

}



// Add the mapView lifecycle to the activity's lifecycle methods
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}


public class TelemetryServiceNotConfiguredException extends RuntimeException {

    public TelemetryServiceNotConfiguredException() {
        super("\nTelemetryService is not configured in your applications AndroidManifest.xml. " +
                "\nPlease add \"com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.telemetry.TelemetryService\" service in your applications AndroidManifest.xml" +
                "\nFor an example visit  For more information visit https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/.");
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Mapbox using exact method name as GoogleMap. If so, you can try adding `map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(YourLatLng, 15))` after you successfully add the marker. You also can use

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
.target(YourLatLng)      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
.zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
.bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
.tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
.build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder

map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

to animate the camera.

**Note**: 15 is the zoom level.

**Zoom Level**

> 1: World
>
> 5: Landmass/continent
>
> 10: City
>
> 15: Streets
>
> 20: Buildings

Comment: Thanks Amad Yus, I will try and reply back

Comment: Hi Amad, Add the code after adding marker, but system is throwing following error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.animateCamera(com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraUpdate)' on a null object reference

Comment: How about moveCamera? Have you tried it? animateCamera just an option. If possible, can you post your full code. I think you have wrongly implementing mapView.

Comment: I have updated your code. Check and fixed your code accordingly and re-run again. In your getMapAsync, when the map is ready, you need to initialize 'map' with 'mapboxMap'. You need to ensure that your 'map' variable is not null. I have put comment in your code above. When you run the code, please check your log for MapAsync. Ensure that you get "MapAsync is called". Because I read a lot of issue on 'onMapReady' is not called in Mapbox - https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/4439

Comment: Awesome !  Amad, All good,  it is working now with your updated code.Thank you very much.